react native app crash when click on snooze button from notification
I created a simple react native app in which i place one button named as "send reminder" when click on that button i got notification after 15 seconds which vibrates for 10 seconds with snooze button within that notification. Now i want that when i click on that snooze button notification should close and vibration should also stops and after 5 minutes same notification comes again which also vibrates . Everything  works fine but when i click on snooze button my app crash with this error on logcat
 Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2024-07-16 09:20:13.583 15520-15615 RNPushNotification      com.stickynotes                      W  Unable to find com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color in manifest. Falling back to default
2024-07-16 09:20:17.949 15520-15520 RNPushNotification      com.stickynotes                      I  RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver loading scheduled notifications
2024-07-16 09:20:17.966 15520-15520 AndroidRuntime          com.stickynotes                      D  Shutting down VM
2024-07-16 09:20:17.972 15520-15520 AndroidRuntime          com.stickynotes                      E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.stickynotes, PID: 15520
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS broadcast from com.stickynotes (pid=15520, uid=10599) requires android.permission.BROADCAST_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS.
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4506)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:204)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:291)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8134)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:601)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1019)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS broadcast from com.stickynotes (pid=15520, uid=10599) requires android.permission.BROADCAST_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS.
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3021)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3005)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2988)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2930)
                                                                                                        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.broadcastIntentWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:5937)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1228)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:500)
                                                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:500)
                                                                                                        at com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions.onReceive(RNPushNotificationActions.java:65)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4497)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2239) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:204) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:291) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8134) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:601) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1019) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.checkCanCloseSystemDialogs(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:3398)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService$LocalService.checkCanCloseSystemDialogs(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:6079)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:15304)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:14819)
                                                                                                        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:15777)

my app.js code is
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, Vibration } from 'react-native';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        if (notification.action === 'Snooze') {
          handleSnoozeAction();
        }
      },
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSendReminder = () => {
    // Schedule notification after 15 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      PushNotification.localNotification({
        channelId: 'default-channel',
        title: 'Reminder Notification',
        message: "Don't forget to take a break!",
        actions: ['Snooze'],
      });

      // Start continuous vibration for 10 seconds
      const vibrationInterval = setInterval(() => {
        Vibration.vibrate(1000); // Vibrate for 1 second
      }, 1000);

      // Stop vibration after 10 seconds
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(vibrationInterval);
        Vibration.cancel();
      }, 10000); // 10 seconds
    }, 15000); // 15 seconds
  };

  const handleSnoozeAction = () => {
    // Clear all notifications and vibrations
    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
    Vibration.cancel();

    // Schedule a new notification and vibration after 2 minutes
    setTimeout(() => {
      PushNotification.localNotification({
        channelId: 'default-channel',
        title: 'Reminder Notification',
        message: "Don't forget to take a break!",
        actions: ['Snooze'],
      });

      // Start continuous vibration for 10 seconds
      const vibrationInterval = setInterval(() => {
        Vibration.vibrate(1000); // Vibrate for 1 second
      }, 1000);

      // Stop vibration after 10 seconds
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(vibrationInterval);
        Vibration.cancel();
      }, 10000); // 10 seconds
    }, 120000); // 2 minutes
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome to My App</Text>
      <Button title="Set Reminder" onPress={handleSendReminder} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

export default App;


Instead of trying to close the system notification directly, you can update your app's notification behavior to dismiss or update the notification when the snooze action is clicked.
When the snooze action is clicked, update the notification to schedule a new notification for the snooze time period. You can cancel the current notification and schedule a new one using the PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule method.
Modified Code :
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet, Vibration } from 'react-native';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        if (notification.action === 'Snooze') {
          handleSnoozeAction();
        }
      },
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSendReminder = () => {
    // Schedule notification after 15 seconds
    const notificationId = 'reminder-notification';
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      channelId: 'default-channel',
      title: 'Reminder Notification',
      message: "Don't forget to take a break!",
      actions: ['Snooze'],
      id: notificationId,
    });

    // Start continuous vibration for 10 seconds
    const vibrationInterval = setInterval(() => {
      Vibration.vibrate(1000); // Vibrate for 1 second
    }, 1000);

    // Stop vibration after 10 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(vibrationInterval);
      Vibration.cancel();
    }, 10000); // 10 seconds
  };

  const handleSnoozeAction = () => {
    // Cancel the current notification
    const notificationId = 'reminder-notification';
    PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: notificationId });

    // Schedule a new notification and vibration after 5 minutes (300000 milliseconds)
    const snoozeTime = 300000; // 5 minutes
    setTimeout(() => {
      handleSendReminder(); // Reschedule the reminder
    }, snoozeTime);

    // Stop current vibration
    Vibration.cancel();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome to My App</Text>
      <Button title="Set Reminder" onPress={handleSendReminder} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
});

export default App;

So Make sure you have installed, given permissions and linked correctly.
(a) Check android/build.gradle has
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
        ...
    }
}

(b) Check In android/app/build.gradle
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
  implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
  ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

(c) Check In MainApplication.java
import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;

(d) Check In android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml (Create the file if it doesn't exist).
<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFF</color>
</resources>

(e) Check In android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
.....
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application ....>
        <!-- Change the value to true to enable pop-up for in foreground (remote-only, for local use ignoreInForeground) -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_foreground"
                    android:value="false"/>
        <!-- Change the resource name to your App's accent color - or any other color you want -->
        <meta-data  android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_color"
                    android:resource="@color/white"/> <!-- or @android:color/{name} to use a standard color -->

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationActions" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
     .....


after adding that permission i got
"Permission is only granted to system apps More... (Ctrl+F1)
Inspection info:Permissions with the protection level signature, privileged or signatureOrSystem are only granted to system apps. If an app is a regular non-system app, it will never be able to use these permissions.  Issue id: ProtectedPermissions Vendor: Android Open Source Project"

Please check the updated code, Thanks.
